# How to control the font of a symbol in plot?

Tags: r, plot

In R, in the plot() function, pch argument controls the appearance of the symbols. For exemple pch=3, but is it possible to make this symbol bold, something like font.symbol = 2?

Comment: it's make the characters bold but not a symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using symbols with lines, it looks like `lwd` might get what you're after:

```
plot(1:10, lwd = rep(1:5, 2), cex = 2)
```

[image]